# C# windows service ip адрес

Tags: c#

Как получить ип адрес компьютера в переменную?

Comment: Какой? 127.0.0.1 подойдёт?

Comment: а ты в курсе что этих айпи у компьюета дофига? Если у тебя стоит езернет и вайфай, то их уже 2. Если еще виртуальная сеть настроена еще один. Если еще и прокси -- еще один. А еще у одной железяки может быть 4 и 6й версии... одновременно... Тебе какой?

Comment: ну собственно виртуальной сети поднятой роутером, подключение проводное)

Comment: Ну тогда вариант только один, сначала делай выборку сетевых карт по названию адаптера, а потом по выбранному адаптеру доставай айпишник. Что бы увидеть полную выборку твоих сетевых введи в консоль `ipconfig /all` . И да, это не виртуальная сеть уже ('виртуальной сети поднятой роутером') если уж она поднята роутером, то это сеть вполне реальная. Ответ проапдейтил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение сработает далеко не на любой машине:

```
public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
{
    var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            return ip.ToString();
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
}
```

оно может возвращать неправильный результат если есть виртуальные сетевые карты или несколько физических.

---

upd:

```
NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (var adapter in interfaces)
{
    // здесь ищешь адаптер по нужным параметрам
    // и здесь же достаешь айпишник
}
```

Comment: DNS вообще может быть не настроен, недоступен или заблокирован...

Comment: @Akina полностью, абсолютно и бесповоротно согласен) Каков  ̶с̶т̶о̶л̶ ̶т̶а̶к̶о̶й̶ ̶и̶ ̶с̶т̶у̶л̶  вопрос такой и ответ.